# NodeJS Post request using a Button

Tags: node.js, express

I don't know if this is possible or not. All the research I've done has shown that it is possible with a form and text input. But anyways, Using NodeJs & Express I want to be able to click a button on my webpage, and once it's clicked, it sends a post request to my Node.JS server.

Simpler way of saying it:
When button is clicked, send info to the server.

Goal I'm trying to achieve:
When button is clicked, it sends some sort of ID/code/anything to turn on a service from my database. (I have yet to learn how db's work so I am just trying to focus on front end.)

Code I have so far:

```
app.post("/send", function(req, res){
  var newID = req.body.ID;
  res.redirect("/action")
});

<form action="/send" method="POST">
    <input type="button" name="newID" placeholder="Button">
    <button>send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 12):

You do not need to use jQuery or AJAX.

Simply add an `input` of type `submit` inside the `form` tag so that the POST request defined by your `form` tag is submitted.

Your `newID` input should be of type `text`, this allows entering a value in the input field.

The `newID` value can be retrieved server side with `req.body.newID` (be sure to use the body-parser middleware).

```
<form action="/send" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="newID" placeholder="Enter your ID"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Click here to submit the form"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purposes you should use `$.ajax`, 
example:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/send',
      data: { ID: 'someid' },
      success: function(resultData) {
         alert(resultData);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Would I use this code on my node.JS server or would I use it on my html/ejs file?

Comment: you should use it in your html/js file but first include: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` this code in html document