# express: POST request with button click

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to insert data at a database table when a button in pressed. So I have the below code in my `register.html` file

```
<form action="/send" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="newID" placeholder="Enter your ID"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Send Data"/>
</form>
```

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619516/nodejs-post-request-using-a-button), I have below code in my `app.js`

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
  var newID = req.body.newID
  console.log(newID)
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/background.html'));
}
```

Now when I write something in the text box and press the button, the page just moves to `localhost:8080/send` which shows the contents of background.html. But I don't see the `newID` value in the javascript `console`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code looks fine, maybe you are submitting empty value .?

Comment: You don't see `newID` in javascript console because it never prints anything to this browser console. Remember that this is NodeJS – server side process. So you should check your terminal where you run your server.

Answer (score 0):

**I WAS WRONG THIS IS NODE.JS NOTHING WILL BE PRINTED TO THE BROWSER CONSOLE**

```
   pp.post('/send', function(req, res) {
      var newID = req.body.newID
      console.log(newID)
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/background.html'));
    }
```

This is going to print "newID" to the console and then transfer you to a different page. Not all web browsers store console data when your URL changes. So it could be working but before you can view the console yourself it may be cleaning all the temporary data out to make room for whats coming on the next page. This could answer your question as to why you don't see anything.

Comment: No, this console.log is not going to be printed to browser console at all. This is nodejs console log.